# Function Evaluator doesnt work in network analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, route

I made a function in my evaluator (% of asphalt in my route), but for some reason, it doesnt work.
The idea of the script is to se the % of asphalt in my route, so basically the equation is

```
(km of asphalt)/(km of my total route)
```

It is a really simple equation, but when I try to insert this evaluator, the network does not solve, and a message like this appears:

> Error: The evaluator failed to return a value. [Attribute: Distance,
>   Source: TF_4589, OID = 42, EID = 46897]

Anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Maybe something is wrong in the record of OID = 42 . Is it Null value?

Comment: No, all my lines have their atributes, I checked that.